# Access Android phone camera stream using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, android-camera

I am developing an application that performs live streaming. Currently, I am able to stream a local video from my SD card to my Wowza streaming server successfully.

This is the command that I fire from my FFMPEG based Android project

```
 ffmpeg -re -i /sdcard/sample.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.34:1936/live/myStream
```

Now, I want to send my camera stream to my streaming server.
I tried using the below command but it does not work since the /dev/video0 device is denied permission.

```
   ffmpeg -re -i /dev/video0 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.34:1936/live/myStream
```

Can anyone tell me the right way to stream the camera feed using ffmpeg on Android

Comment: you can give a try with, two steps implementation, from your application you will be writing camera stream to one file and you can stream that file using ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't provide direct access to Android camera. It sounds like a native Android library [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreamin) to perform this task. The license is GPL, as ffmpeg.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki: I have tried doing that. It works that way but that would be like video on demand..it wont be live streaming.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Do you have any reasons for that? I got this idea from this video --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d5lzKk1hPU . I have used libstreaming but the problem is I wish to stream using h.265 which is currently not supported by libstreaming but supported by ffmpeg only

Comment: You are right, libstagefright will not produce H265. But even with ffmpeg, the example that you show [works with the HW encoder via stagefright](https://github.com/dmonakhov/libav/commit/3868238873785d899cc6b542331fe9fe81870c59), so it is the same H264 stream as with libstreaming.